# package ‘vegan’ was installed by an R version with different internals

Tags: r, vegan

I have installed R-3.4.4 for Windows (32/64 bit) and RStudio 1.1.442 - Windows Vista/7/8/10. I installed package of vegan 2.4-6. When I try opening it then I get the message:

```
> install.packages("C:/Users/Na Talia/Rpackages/vegan_2.4-6.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Na Talia/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’

(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

package ‘vegan’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

> library("vegan", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.4")

Error: package ‘vegan’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version

In addition: Warning message:
package ‘vegan’ was built under R version 3.5.0
```

Any help? Thank you for your time in advance.

P.S. I get the same message in R as well. I reinstalled vegan several times but nothing helps.

Comment: Well, apparently you don't have the correct binary for your R version. Three options: 1. Don't install from a local copy. Install directly from a CRAN mirror. 2. Get the correct binary. 3. Install from source.

Comment: Both R and Roland told you that you have a wrong binary version of vegan: You said you have R-3.4.4, but R said that vegan was built under (yet unreleased) R-3.5.0. The CRAN archive has vegan_2.4-6.zip both for r-devel (= 3.5.0) and r-release (=3.4.4). Pick the r-release binary.

Comment: Thank you both for replay. I picked the r-release binary and its working now.

Comment: @N T: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are accessing the package from `lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.4"`, you should be installing the package in that directory.
You can use the command as

`install.packages("C:/Users/Na Talia/Rpackages/vegan_2.4-6.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary", lib = "~/R/win-library/3.4")`

Without specifying the lib path, R uses the first element of .libPaths().

Comment: This question was resolved over a year ago in the comments. Now you post an answer that does not address the underlying issue that OP has already confirmed in the comments it was.