# R & Package Incompability (Fiji)

Tags: r, package, imagej, installation-package, fiji

Others have experienced and posted this issue here.  See:

[Error: package was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50144957/error-package-was-installed-by-an-r-version-with-different-internals-it-needs)

and

[package ‘vegan’ was installed by an R version with different internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527227/package-vegan-was-installed-by-an-r-version-with-different-internals)

for identical issues with varying R packages.
I too, followed the solutions presented in these threads to which R responded positively.  However, Fiji did not.  I received the following message in the R Console:

[ERROR] File has length 0 and may be corrupt
Rserve>Starting Rserve...
Rserve> "C:\Users\LENOVO~1\DOCUME~1\R\WIN-LI~1\3.5\Rserve\libs\x64\Rserve.exe" --no-save --slave

The instructions for use of the plugin I am attempting to learn and master reside here:

https://imagej.net/ParticleSizer

I am running Fiji/ImageJ 1.52g.

Note despite following these for the installation of R (3.5.1) this does not agree with the stipulated version of Rserve (1.8-0.zip).  MASS installed from the local zipfile as indicated.  R informed me it wanted Rserve 1.7-3.  After downloaded 1.7-3.zip R was happy.

I am working with an older ThinkPad running 64-bit Win7 Pro, 8 GB RAM and a 2.67 GHz first generation Core i5 M 560.

Any insight you can offer is appreciated.

Edit on Oct. 8, 2018 - I have continued to work with this and been unable to resolve the issue with installing Rserve from the local zipfile as instructed.  For this reason, I uninstalled R completely.

I have now installed R 3.5.1 a second time and did not install the 32-bit files.  When I attempt to install Rserve-1.8-0.zip from my local file the R Console tells me nothing.  However, when I install the local package file MASS_7.3-45.zip I see the following indication it has been installed successfully in the console:

package ‘MASS’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

I hope this additional information helps.

Rick

Comment: I'm confused about what your question is.  If it isn't about conflicting internals  I think you should edit that part out.  What  precisely did you type that resulted in that message?  Are you saying you solved it by installing an older vesion?   Also can you please explain what operating system + version you are on?

Comment: Conflicting internals is a component of the larger problem.  I ran the Fiji plugin, ParticleSizer, and R informed me the recommended version of Rserve was built with different internals.  The recommendation for MASS was as described.  I concluded Rserve was the issue so, chose to download a new version of it from a mirror near me and install it from the local zipfiles as I had done previously.  To my surprise this resulted in an older version of Rserve than that recommended.  Nonetheless, R informed me it was happy with the new yet, older version of Rserve.  ParticleSizer is still not happy.

Comment: The older version of R satisfies R 3.5.1 not the Fiji plugin.  RForge explains that 1.8-0 is not posted on CRAN.

Comment: You should post the whole explanation as an answer which you can then accept it.

Comment: I understand your perspective yet, I cannot regard what I have determined as an answer or solution.  This is because, I am unable to make R or the Fiji plugin execute as desired.  If I had been able to make both Fiji and R happy then I would agree with you.